# Crashed visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I run visual studio unit test then my VS all text becomes unreadable, I running in virtual box windows 7, visual studio 2019
[image: All text and code in the studio changes]

It helps to restart the studio and so with all projects
How to fix it?

Comment: as you said: "restart the studio" ?   (or provide more details about the unit test that is causing this problem)

Comment: It is enough to run hello world on C# cmd app and the text will become symbols

Comment: [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 doesn't work either

Comment: repair didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing the correct video driver on the virtual box